# how to refresh a window on the fly in PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

how are you?

I wrote a code using the PySimpleGui library that works as follows: It starts a first window where the user will put an input and when proceeding and clicking opens a second window where the objective is that it is the user's monitoring terminal.

The problem is that I can't print in the second window in realtime. By clicking "OK" the code starts and starts to automate it, but the second window only shows the content printed after the code is finished, I can't make it print in real time, along with the code's actions. Testei usar o Window.update e Window.refresh porém não obtive sucesso.

second window = janela_acompanhamento

```
from PySimpleGUI import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PySimpleGUI import *
import pyautogui 
import time 
import os 
t = time.sleep

gui = pyautogui

os.system('cls') # limpa o terminal
users = ['GUILHERME','GABRIEL','MATHEUS','RAUL','SATO','MAURICE']
workers = ['WORKER01','WORKER02','WORKER03','WORKER04']
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
global values
global hand 

hand= sg.InputText(key ='hand',do_not_clear = True, size =(20,1))
canal = sg.InputText(key ="canal", size =(20,1))
sleep1 = sg.InputText(key ="sleep1", size =(20,1))
sleep2 = sg.InputText(key ="sleep2", size =(20,1))
par = sg.InputText(key ="par", size =(20,1))
perc = sg.InputText(key ="perc", size =(20,1))
usu = sg.Listbox(users, key = 'usu',size = (20,1))
worker = sg.Listbox(workers, key = 'worker', select_mode="",size = (20,1))



    layout1 = [
    
        [Image(filename='2.png')],
        [sg.Text('Bem Vindo Usário, siga o questionamento para identificar seus dados:', size = (50,1))],
        [sg.Text("VALOR DA MÃO?" ,size = (25,1)),hand],
        [sg.Text("CANAL DE TRABALHO?", size = (25,1)),canal],
        [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA LATERAL? " ,size = (25,1)),sleep1],
        [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA VERTICAL?" ,size = (25,1)),sleep2],
        [sg.Text("QUAL PAR VOCÊ QUER?" ,size = (25,1)),par],
        [sg.Text("QUAL RANGE VOCÊ QUER?" ,size = (25,1)),perc],
        [sg.Text("QUAL PERFIL?",size =(25,1)),usu],  # SELECT MODE = MULTIPLE PARA SELECIONAR MAIS DE UMA OPÇÃO AO MESMO TEMPO 
        [sg.Text("QUAL WORKER?",size =(25,1)),worker], 
        [sg.Text("QUAL PRAZO?",size =(24,1)),sg.Radio("LONGO","prazo",True,key="longoprazo"),sg.Radio("CURTO","prazo",key="curtoprazo")], # sg.radio são definidas como True or False, então crie uma função 
        [sg.Text("QUAL LADO?",size =(24,1)),sg.Radio("DOWN","lado",True,key="ladodown"),sg.Radio("UP","lado",key="ladoup")],
        [sg.Button("Entrar"), sg.Button("Cancelar")],
        ]
    
    def abrir_putty():
        gui.press('Win');t(0.5);
        gui.write('PUTTY');t(0.5);gui.press('Return');t(1);gui.write('temporario');t(1);gui.press('Return');t(3) #gui.write(values['usu'][0])
        gui.write('batata123');gui.press('Return')    
    
    def janela_acompanhamento(values2): 
        janela_layout =  [ 
    
                [sg.Text('DILLO BOT - INICIALIZADOR')],
                [sg.Output(size=(90,30), key='-OUTPUT-', font ='bold' )],
                [sg.Button('OK')]]
        janela_acompanhamento = sg.Window("Janela de Acompanhamento", janela_layout)
    
        while True: 
            event, values = janela_acompanhamento.read(timeout=250)
            if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Fechar'): 
                break
            elif event == 'Entrar': 
             janela_acompanhamento.read
            elif event == 'OK':
                
                print("PROTOCOLO"+" "+"---->", end="  ");
                print("U:"+values2['usu'][0],end="  ")
                print("W:"+values2['worker'][0], end = " ")
                print("M:"+values2["hand"],end="  ")
                print("P:"+values2["par"],end="  ")
                print("R:"+values2["perc"],end="  ")
                print("C:"+values2["canal"],end="  ")
                print("S1:"+values2["sleep1"],end="  ")
                print("S2:"+values2["sleep2"],end="  ")
                if values2['longoprazo'] == True: 
                    print("P:"+'LONGO')
                else: 
                    print("P:"+'CURTO')
    
                if values2['ladodown'] == True: 
                    print("L:"+'DOWN')
                else: 
                    print("L:"+'UP')
                    
                abrir_putty()
                print("O DILLO ESTÁ INICIANDO")
                janela_acompanhamento.Refresh()
        
    
    window = sg.Window('Dillo Bot', layout1)
    while True: 
        event, values = window.read()
        sg.theme('DarkAmber')
        if event in (None, "Quit"):
            break
        if event == 'Cancelar':
            break
        if event == 'Entrar': 
            window.hide()
            janela_acompanhamento(values)
    window.close()
    
    
    '''
            while True: 
                janela1.hide()
                event, values = janela.read()
                print('event:', event)
                print('values:', values)
                hand = values['hand']
                janela['-OUTPUT-'].upadate(int(hand))
    janela.close()
    '''
```

Comment: Not to use Output element, try use Multiline element with option `reroute_stdout=True`. GUI will update only when the execution back to `window.read()`, or you can call `window.refresh()` to update GUI immediately.

Comment: Please don't `import *`.  You only need `import PySimpleGUI as sg`.

Comment: A tip - search the PySimpleGUI docs at PySimpleGUI.org.  You have the right word in the title "refresh". In the call reference, seraching for refresh shows that in every `update` method is the explanation "`"Changes will not be visible in your window until you call window.read or window.refresh."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things stand out in your code that I'll paste the a modified version.

1. Your import of PySimpleGUI should be `import PySimpleGUI as sg`

   - You'll need to add "sg." to your `Image` element definition after changing it. That's all I found that was impacted by the fix.
2. Your program is crashing in the second window (likely because I'm simply clicking "Entrar" without anything else being set.

   - Comment out the `Output` element so you can see on your screen what's printed.  If your program crashes, your windows will close, leaving you no debug information
   - These are 2 lines that crash:

```py
                print("U:"+values2['usu'][0],end="  ")
                print("W:"+values2['worker'][0], end = " ")
```

3. Your first window is never restored after returning from the second.  Add a call to `window.un_hide()`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyautogui 
import time 
import os 
t = time.sleep

gui = pyautogui

os.system('cls') # limpa o terminal
users = ['GUILHERME','GABRIEL','MATHEUS','RAUL','SATO','MAURICE']
workers = ['WORKER01','WORKER02','WORKER03','WORKER04']
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
global values
global hand 

hand= sg.InputText(key ='hand',do_not_clear = True, size =(20,1))
canal = sg.InputText(key ="canal", size =(20,1))
sleep1 = sg.InputText(key ="sleep1", size =(20,1))
sleep2 = sg.InputText(key ="sleep2", size =(20,1))
par = sg.InputText(key ="par", size =(20,1))
perc = sg.InputText(key ="perc", size =(20,1))
usu = sg.Listbox(users, key = 'usu',size = (20,1))
worker = sg.Listbox(workers, key = 'worker', select_mode="",size = (20,1))



    layout1 = [
    
        [sg.Image(filename='2.png')],
        [sg.Text('Bem Vindo Usário, siga o questionamento para identificar seus dados:', size = (50,1))],
        [sg.Text("VALOR DA MÃO?" ,size = (25,1)),hand],
        [sg.Text("CANAL DE TRABALHO?", size = (25,1)),canal],
        [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA LATERAL? " ,size = (25,1)),sleep1],
        [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA VERTICAL?" ,size = (25,1)),sleep2],
        [sg.Text("QUAL PAR VOCÊ QUER?" ,size = (25,1)),par],
        [sg.Text("QUAL RANGE VOCÊ QUER?" ,size = (25,1)),perc],
        [sg.Text("QUAL PERFIL?",size =(25,1)),usu],  # SELECT MODE = MULTIPLE PARA SELECIONAR MAIS DE UMA OPÇÃO AO MESMO TEMPO 
        [sg.Text("QUAL WORKER?",size =(25,1)),worker], 
        [sg.Text("QUAL PRAZO?",size =(24,1)),sg.Radio("LONGO","prazo",True,key="longoprazo"),sg.Radio("CURTO","prazo",key="curtoprazo")], # sg.radio são definidas como True or False, então crie uma função 
        [sg.Text("QUAL LADO?",size =(24,1)),sg.Radio("DOWN","lado",True,key="ladodown"),sg.Radio("UP","lado",key="ladoup")],
        [sg.Button("Entrar"), sg.Button("Cancelar")],
        ]
    
    def abrir_putty():
        gui.press('Win');t(0.5);
        gui.write('PUTTY');t(0.5);gui.press('Return');t(1);gui.write('temporario');t(1);gui.press('Return');t(3) #gui.write(values['usu'][0])
        gui.write('batata123');gui.press('Return')    
    
    def janela_acompanhamento(values2): 
        janela_layout =  [ 
    
                [sg.Text('DILLO BOT - INICIALIZADOR')],
                [sg.Output(size=(90,30), key='-OUTPUT-', font ='bold' )],
                [sg.Button('OK')]]
        janela_acompanhamento = sg.Window("Janela de Acompanhamento", janela_layout)
    
        while True: 
            event, values = janela_acompanhamento.read(timeout=250)
            if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Fechar'): 
                break
            elif event == 'Entrar': 
             janela_acompanhamento.read
            elif event == 'OK':
                
                print("PROTOCOLO"+" "+"---->", end="  ");
                print("U:"+values2['usu'][0],end="  ")
                print("W:"+values2['worker'][0], end = " ")
                print("M:"+values2["hand"],end="  ")
                print("P:"+values2["par"],end="  ")
                print("R:"+values2["perc"],end="  ")
                print("C:"+values2["canal"],end="  ")
                print("S1:"+values2["sleep1"],end="  ")
                print("S2:"+values2["sleep2"],end="  ")
                if values2['longoprazo'] == True: 
                    print("P:"+'LONGO')
                else: 
                    print("P:"+'CURTO')
    
                if values2['ladodown'] == True: 
                    print("L:"+'DOWN')
                else: 
                    print("L:"+'UP')
                    
                abrir_putty()
                print("O DILLO ESTÁ INICIANDO")
                janela_acompanhamento.Refresh()
        
    
    window = sg.Window('Dillo Bot', layout1)
    while True: 
        event, values = window.read()
        sg.theme('DarkAmber')
        if event in (None, "Quit"):
            break
        if event == 'Cancelar':
            break
        if event == 'Entrar': 
            window.hide()
            janela_acompanhamento(values)
    window.close()
    
    
    '''
            while True: 
                janela1.hide()
                event, values = janela.read()
                print('event:', event)
                print('values:', values)
                hand = values['hand']
                janela['-OUTPUT-'].upadate(int(hand))
    janela.close()
    '''
```

---

This is your code with the above modifications, with the `Output` element returned.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyautogui
import time
import os

t = time.sleep

gui = pyautogui

os.system('cls')  # limpa o terminal
users = ['GUILHERME', 'GABRIEL', 'MATHEUS', 'RAUL', 'SATO', 'MAURICE']
workers = ['WORKER01', 'WORKER02', 'WORKER03', 'WORKER04']
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
global values
global hand

hand = sg.InputText(key='hand', do_not_clear=True, size=(20, 1))
canal = sg.InputText(key="canal", size=(20, 1))
sleep1 = sg.InputText(key="sleep1", size=(20, 1))
sleep2 = sg.InputText(key="sleep2", size=(20, 1))
par = sg.InputText(key="par", size=(20, 1))
perc = sg.InputText(key="perc", size=(20, 1))
usu = sg.Listbox(users, key='usu', size=(20, 1))
worker = sg.Listbox(workers, key='worker', select_mode="", size=(20, 1))

layout1 = [

    [sg.Image(filename='2.png')],
    [sg.Text('Bem Vindo Usário, siga o questionamento para identificar seus dados:', size=(50, 1))],
    [sg.Text("VALOR DA MÃO?", size=(25, 1)), hand],
    [sg.Text("CANAL DE TRABALHO?", size=(25, 1)), canal],
    [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA LATERAL? ", size=(25, 1)), sleep1],
    [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA VERTICAL?", size=(25, 1)), sleep2],
    [sg.Text("QUAL PAR VOCÊ QUER?", size=(25, 1)), par],
    [sg.Text("QUAL RANGE VOCÊ QUER?", size=(25, 1)), perc],
    [sg.Text("QUAL PERFIL?", size=(25, 1)), usu],  # SELECT MODE = MULTIPLE PARA SELECIONAR MAIS DE UMA OPÇÃO AO MESMO TEMPO
    [sg.Text("QUAL WORKER?", size=(25, 1)), worker],
    [sg.Text("QUAL PRAZO?", size=(24, 1)), sg.Radio("LONGO", "prazo", True, key="longoprazo"), sg.Radio("CURTO", "prazo", key="curtoprazo")],
    # sg.radio são definidas como True or False, então crie uma função
    [sg.Text("QUAL LADO?", size=(24, 1)), sg.Radio("DOWN", "lado", True, key="ladodown"), sg.Radio("UP", "lado", key="ladoup")],
    [sg.Button("Entrar"), sg.Button("Cancelar")],
]


def abrir_putty():
    gui.press('Win');
    t(0.5);
    gui.write('PUTTY');
    t(0.5);
    gui.press('Return');
    t(1);
    gui.write('temporario');
    t(1);
    gui.press('Return');
    t(3)  # gui.write(values['usu'][0])
    gui.write('batata123');
    gui.press('Return')


def janela_acompanhamento(values2):
    janela_layout = [

        [sg.Text('DILLO BOT - INICIALIZADOR')],
        [sg.Output(size=(90, 30), key='-OUTPUT-', font='bold')],
        [sg.Button('OK')]]
    janela_acompanhamento = sg.Window("Janela de Acompanhamento", janela_layout)

    while True:
        event, values = janela_acompanhamento.read(timeout=250)
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Fechar'):
            break
        elif event == 'Entrar':
            janela_acompanhamento.read
        elif event == 'OK':

            print("PROTOCOLO" + " " + "---->", end="  ");
            # print("U:" + values2['usu'][0], end="  ")
            # print("W:" + values2['worker'][0], end=" ")
            print("M:" + values2["hand"], end="  ")
            print("P:" + values2["par"], end="  ")
            print("R:" + values2["perc"], end="  ")
            print("C:" + values2["canal"], end="  ")
            print("S1:" + values2["sleep1"], end="  ")
            print("S2:" + values2["sleep2"], end="  ")
            if values2['longoprazo'] == True:
                print("P:" + 'LONGO')
            else:
                print("P:" + 'CURTO')

            if values2['ladodown'] == True:
                print("L:" + 'DOWN')
            else:
                print("L:" + 'UP')

            abrir_putty()
            print("O DILLO ESTÁ INICIANDO")
            janela_acompanhamento.Refresh()


window = sg.Window('Dillo Bot', layout1)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    sg.theme('DarkAmber')
    if event in (None, "Quit"):
        break
    if event == 'Cancelar':
        break
    if event == 'Entrar':
        window.hide()
        janela_acompanhamento(values)
        window.un_hide()
window.close()

'''
        while True:
            janela1.hide()
            event, values = janela.read()
            print('event:', event)
            print('values:', values)
            hand = values['hand']
            janela['-OUTPUT-'].upadate(int(hand))
janela.close()
'''
```